# Juju - no matching node available

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.2 and running juju environment as MaaS, have 1 node only as the bootstrapped node.
Before bootstrap I did juju sync-tools and then juju bootstrap.
After the bootstrap I did 2x juju add-machine and then juju status, got this:

[image]

How do I solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one node.  One node is allocated for juju-gui.  You are asking for 2 more nodes.

You only have one node, and it is in use, so you have no matching nodes available.

If you are using VMs, you need to build two more.

If you are using hardware, you need to buy more.